# how to i programaitcally go to a textField after endEditing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

i have a text field, when i hit enter, my textfield string gets sent to a textView. each time i enter a new line in the textfield, it takes that string and appends it to the textView.

what i need to do is be able to continuously type and press enter, appending to my textView without having the need to reselect the textField

in viewDidLoad;

```
- (void)setupFloatTextBox {
CGFloat screenWidth = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;
CGFloat screenHeight = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;

UITextField *noteTextField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, screenHeight - 55, screenWidth - 5, 30)];
noteTextField.backgroundColor = Rbg2UIColor(51, 182, 124);
[noteTextField.layer setBorderWidth:0.5f];
[noteTextField setAlpha:0.5f];
[noteTextField addTarget:self action:@selector(postJSON:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingDidEnd];
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:noteTextField];
}
```

and my selector action

```
- (void)postJSON:(UITextField *)sender {
if (sender.text.length > 0) {
    FireStormClasses *fs = [[FireStormClasses alloc] init];
    fs.CATEGORY = @"TASK";
    fs.TASK = [sender.text substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(3, sender.text.length - 3)];
    fs.WHO = [[sender.text substringToIndex:2] uppercaseString];
    fs.PRIORITY = @"0";
    fs.ACTION = @"UPDATED";
    fs.HIDDEN = @"0";
    fs.UDATE = [FireStorm getCurrentDateWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    fs.DUEDATE = [FireStorm getCurrentDateWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    fs.COMPLETEDATE = [FireStorm getCurrentDateWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    fs.LISTDATE = [FireStorm getCurrentDateWithFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];

    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"myurl"];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [manager POST:URL.absoluteString
       parameters:[fs postCreateJSON]
         progress:nil
          success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
              NSLog(@"%@", responseObject);
              [self loadJSONData];
          }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error) {
              NSLog(@"%@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:(NSData *)error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
              NSLog(@"%@", error);
          }];

    sender.text = @"";
    [sender resignFirstResponder];
    [sender becomeFirstResponder];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Texfield empty");
} 
}
```

the lines `sender resignFirstResponder];` and `[sender becomeFirstResponder];` i am using to make my textfield active/inactive.

the issue im having is, on first type/enter, im taken back to my textfield where i can continue typing, however upon hitting enter the second time, the button does nothing.

[heres a video explaining a bit better](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dtiglze6sjiolzn/IMG_0240.mov?dl=0) (sorry for the crash, skip to 20 seconds in)

Comment: Just as a tip, please don't give huge sections of code like with your second code block. It makes it more difficult to pick out the code relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

instead of add target to textfield ,just set the delegate for that textfield and in the delegate method of the UITextfield set,

```
-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

it will solve Your Problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UIControlEventEditingDidEnd, use UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification. Then you can look for end of line to decide to update, ignore the rest.